# When building array program in Java, it does not return the last number of the array when following the array.length - 1 method

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a small program to take an input array, `nums` and create a new array that is double the size and returns the last number from the previous array as the last and only different number in the new array.

When I try to return this number using the `nums.length - 1` formula to get the end of the array, it returns the number in the middle of the new array. Below is my program.

```
public int[] makeLast(int[] nums) {
    
    int lengonewarr = nums.length;
    
    int officiallength = lengonewarr * 2;
    
    
    int [] makezero = new int [officiallength];
    
    makezero [nums.length-1] = nums[nums.length-1];
    
    return(makezero);
  
}
```

These are the outputs I should be making:

```
makeLast([4, 5, 6]) → [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6]
makeLast([1, 2]) → [0, 0, 0, 2]
makeLast([3]) → [0, 3]
```

But I instead get something like:

```
makeLast([1, 2, 3, 4]) → [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4] (My output) [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]  
makeLast([2, 4]) → [0, 0, 0, 4]  (My output)    [0, 4, 0, 0]
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `makezero [officiallength -1] = nums[nums.length-1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the array `makezero`'s length is `officiallength`, not `nums.length`, just replace the first `nums.length` by `makezero.length` or `officiallength`.

```
makezero [makezero.length -1] = nums[nums.length-1];
```

BTW: It's better to name the variable with camelCase style, which will make the code more readable. Like `makeZero` or `officialLength`

Comment: Yikes! I should have looked closer at the program. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your and here it is:

```
public int[] makeLast(int[] nums) {
    
    int lengonewarr = nums.length;
    
    int officiallength = lengonewarr * 2;
    
    int [] makezero = new int [officiallength];
    
    makezero [makezero.length-1] = nums[nums.length-1];
    
    return(makezero);
  
}
```

As the array `makezero` is double size, the length of `lengonewarr` is always in the middle of `makezero`.